# Supervisord does not work

Tags: supervisord

Kinda shocked about supervisor. I get this error

```
unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file
```

What is so shocking is the file is there! I am running on ubuntu on ec2. I tired to chmod to 0777 as well.

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10          ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=debug               ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false              ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                 ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock

[include]
files = *.supervisor
```

Comment: What raises this error?  If it is `supervisorctl`, is `supervisord` already running?

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this? I'm having a similar problem where supervisord won't start (in my case, /var/run/supervisor.sock is never created).

Answer (score 3):

this was my problem, not sure if it helps. Aparently "`service supervisord start`" doesn't necessarily load your config file, or even a config file at all. In order to make mine work, I had to do a `supervisord -c /path/to/my/config.conf` (i.e. run the binary directly) this fixed everything.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is kinda old but for the sake of others who happen to land to this problem, starting the supervisor daemon works for me.

`sudo service supervisor start`

A more detailed explanation is that in general, when you encounter a "unix:///var/run/blabla.sock no such file" error, most likely the issue is that the daemon of the program in subject (`supervisord` in this case) wasn't started and thus wasn't able to generate the expected unix socket `supervisor.sock` file. This file is the communication endpoint for the supervisor foreground commands (such as `supervisorctl`) that acts as a tunnel/middleman responsible for relaying user-issued commands (ex. `supervisorctl reread`) to the supervisor service running in background.

You can refer to [Unix Domain Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)  and to this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18858970/969645).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently and I fixed it by following the following processes

1). Activate your your virtualenv

2). Ensure supervisor is install in your virtual environment with pip

3). start supervisor as a superuser: $ sudo su

4). run: $ supervisord
or $ supervisorctl start

And that's it.